# Magento backend submit order is not working when merge javascript is yes

Tags: magento, submit

Magento backend submit order functionality is not working when merge javascript script file is yes. If I disable submit order functionality it is working. I use magento CE 1.7

Comment: I think it is conflicting with the javascript at another location. Try to find out the new JavaScript that you have added recently and add 'jQuery.noConflict()' at the starting of the function

Comment: I didnt add any new javascript function

Answer (score 0):

When you merge javascript then some thimes this problem caused. so instead of merge javascript you can use minify javascript or css.